# Directly applying residual bootstrap to the predictions vs. inferring the parameters?

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, bootstrap, residuals

My friend has a procedure where he does the following:

1. Given a dataset $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n, y_n)$ Fit $f$ according to $\hat{y_i} = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$ where $f$ is the regression function.
2. Predict a target $y$ using $f$. Generate a distribution for $y$ by sampling $\hat{\epsilon_i}$ from the set of all $\epsilon_i$ and taking $y + \hat{\epsilon_i}$.
3. Those $y + \hat{\epsilon_i}$ samples are passed in as a parameter to another distribution for further inference.

Is this basically just applying the distribution of the residuals to the target $y$? Have you used something like this in practice?

Most of the descriptions I've seen of residual bootstrap do the following:

1. Fit the model $\hat{y_i} = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$.
2. Simulate $y_i^* = \hat{y_i} + \epsilon_j$ where $\epsilon_j$ is randomly selected from the set of all $\epsilon_i$.
3. Refit $f$ using $(x_i,y_i^*)$ multiple times.

This ends up getting you a set of $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ from each refitting in 3.

If I were to then predict my target $y$ with all of these $f$s and apply that to the another distribution, is there anything you can say about how those results would compare to just applying samples of $\epsilon_i$ to $y$ directly (the first procedure), or is the question too general?

I'm curious why I haven't seen the first procedure described more often vs. the second.

Comment: Maybe some people will think why not re-sampling from $(x_1,y_1)...(x_n,y_n)$ directly.