# How to test if regression coefficients are significantly different?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have two data sets. Both contain survey data where participants had to forecast the return of the same stocks. I ran two regressions one for group 1 and one for group 2 looking like this

```
fixed_model1 <- plm(forecast~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3, data=df1, index=c("user_id", "stock_name"), model="within")

 coeftest1 <- coeftest(fixed_model1 , vcov. = vcovHC, cluster="group") 


coeftest1
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
IV1                 -5.8316     10.3610  -0.1347    0.1458    
IV2                254.9531   239.9216   1.3476    0.2906    
IV3               1733.7329   264.7025   6.4395 1.122e-10 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


fixed_model2 <- plm(forecast~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3, data=df2, index=c("user_id", "stock_name"), model="within")

 coeftest2 <- coeftest(fixed_model2 , vcov. = vcovHC, cluster="group")

coeftest2
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
IV1                 -1.1241     9.0413  -0.1453  0.84811
IV2                 296.3413    235.2937  1.1413  0.35113
IV3                -1756.2563   250.2423 -7.5352 1.1145e-13 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now I would like to test if the slope estimates of IV1, IV2, IV3 are significantly different between both groups. Is there a test I can use in R?

Comment: one way to do this (maybe the standard way) is to combine the two data sets (or not split them in the first place) and estimate the significance of interactions between group and IVx.

Comment: how would I do this? I already have the data sets combined and dummy variable for both studies (1,2). Would I simply define my IVs as IV_1*1 + IV_1*2 + IV_2*1 + IV_2*2 etc.?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this (maybe the standard way) is to combine the two data sets (or not split them in the first place) and estimate the significance of interactions between `group` and `IVx`.

I don't use `plm` much if at all, but the formula

```
 forecast~ group*(IV1 + IV2 + IV3)
```

should produce main effects of `IVx` that correspond to the estimates for group 1 as well as terms with names like `group2:IV1` that represent the between-group differences in effects.

Note that the results will differ *slightly* from those you get when fitting the two groups separately, as the combined model makes the additional assumption that the residual variance is the same for both groups ...

Here are the results you quoted for your combined model (I'm including an effect of study, which you should have seen in the output ...

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
(Intercept)        ?          ?       ?        ?
     study         ?          ?       ?        ?
       IV1   0.69991   17.08859  0.0410   0.9673 
       IV2   4.86949    9.51997  0.5115   0.6091 
 study:IV1 -14.58480   10.93147 -1.3342   0.1823 
 study:IV2   6.22122    5.88201  1.0577   0.2904
```

- `(Intercept)`: expected value for group 1 at IV1=IV2=0
- `study`: expected difference between group 1 and group2 at IV1=IV2=0
- `IV1`: effect of IV1 in group 1
- `IV2`: effect of IV2 in group 1
- `study:IV1`: **difference between groups in effect of IV1**
- `study:IV2`: ditto, for IV2

So for statistical testing the last two p-values are what you're interested in.  Note that the standard error of the `IV1` parameter (effect of IV1 in group 1), and the difference between groups in IV1, and the standard error of the between-group difference in IV1, are all large.  You should *not* say "there was no difference in the effect of IV1 between the groups" (actually, you should never say that): you should say "the estimated effect of IV1 in group 1 was small but highly uncertain: the estimated effect of IV2 in group 2 appears much lower, but the difference is also highly uncertain, so we can't make any clear statements about the direction of the difference" (or something like that ...)

Comment: Do I need to define the group_variables as factors for this to work?

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean ... ?

Comment: Sorry, for not being specific. I meant that I do not understand the output:                         `Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
IV1                                   0.69991   17.08859  0.0410   0.9673
IV2                                  4.86949    9.51997  0.5115   0.6091
study:IV1                       -14.58480   10.93147 -1.3342   0.1823
study:IV2                         6.22122    5.88201  1.0577   0.2904`

Comment: Could you telle me how to interpret these results?

Comment: Did you see my edit?  If so, can you give more information about what's unclear? (I tried to be pretty explicit.)

Comment: Just one questions. Does it matter how the study variable is coded? should it be 0 for study 1 and 1 for study 2 or can it be 1 for study 1 and 2 for study 2?

Comment: 0 for study 1 and 1 for study 2 makes more sense.  (The overall model fit will be the same, and the interaction parameters should be the same, but the `IV1` and `IV2` main effects would be different and weird.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap your coefficients. Randomly sample from each of your populations, fit your regression model repeatedly on the random sample, giving you a distribution of your coefficient for each population.

You can then validate your hypothesis (statistically distinct distributions for each coefficient within each population) using a confidence interval approach based on whatever p-value you want (.01, .05, etc.)

Not an R person, so you'll have to code it yourself.

Comment: What do you think about this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419097/directly-applying-residual-bootstrap-to-the-predictions-vs-inferring-the-parame